# Loop for generating characters in a string, Python random.choice with weights

Tags: python, numpy

**I am trying to write a loop that will generate a random string of defined characters** `'X,T,B,G'` **with a unique set of weights at each position of the string.**

In a loop, the desired output would look like this:

```
['TTGXB',
 'BXTBT',
 'XTBXT',
 'GTTGB',
 'XXBBB',
 'BGXXX',
 'XTXTT',
 'XTTGB',
 'TGBBG',
 'TGXXB']
```

Example with DataFrame:

```
fake_data = {'columnA': ['XTGBT', 'BGXTG', 'GBBBB', 'XGTTT', 'TGTXX', 'BXXTT', 'TTTXX', 'BXXXB', 'TBTBT', 'XBTGT', 'BBXXT']}
df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data, columns = ['columnA'])

new_data = df.columnA.str.split('', n = 5, expand=True).drop(0, axis=1)
stats = new_data.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
stats = stats.apply(lambda x: x.div(x.sum())*100).round(1).fillna(0)
```

`stats.to_numpy()` to get an array of weights to be used for random string generation:

```
array([[36.4, 36.4,  9.1, 27.3, 18.2],
       [ 9.1, 27.3,  9.1,  9.1,  9.1],
       [27.3, 18.2, 45.5, 27.3, 54.5],
       [27.3, 18.2, 36.4, 36.4, 18.2]])
```

**Ideally, I would be able to automate entry of weights from the `np.array` above.**

Comment: It's unclear what end result you're attempting to achieve.  Post an example output.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = []
for _ in range(100):
    array.append(random.choice(pos_1) + random.choice(pos_2)
        + random.choice(pos_3) + random.choice(pos_4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import choices

def random_string(chars, weights, length):
    string = []
    for _ in range(length):
        string += choices(chars, weights=weights)
    return ''.join(string)

chars = list('XTBG')
weights = [0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3]

print(random_string(chars, weights, 4))
# GBTT
```

Edit: Illustrating the use with different weights...

```
weights = [(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), (0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1), (0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2)]

for weight in weights:
    print(random_string(chars, weight, 4))
```

This is more memory efficient that holding a large list of characters:

```
# 872 using sys.getsizeof()
chars = ['X'] * 28 + ['T'] * 21 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 28

# 104 using sys.getsizeof()
weights = [28, 28, 28, 28]

# 80 using sys.getsizeof()
weights = [(28, 28, 28, 28)]
```

You can do similar things with this function, to iterate over different weights, different lengths, and different chars simultaneously. The list of tuples holding weights uses ten times less memory than a list of characters.

Comment: You can use a for-loop, which loops on different weights... And on each iteration, call this function with the new loops. What is better, having a list of weights, or a list with 28 X's, 28 T's, 28, G's, and 28 B's? Or have [(28, 28, 28, 28), (28, 29, 26, 29)], for example.

Answer (score 1):

### Store the equations in a `dict`:

- Retyping things is a pain, inefficient and a waste of time, therefore, store the equations in a `dict` initially, so you:

  1. don't have to retype the equation variable (e.q. `pos_1`).
  2. can easily return a list of equation names with `equations.keys()`
  3. can access the equations using `equations.values()`

#### Data:

```
equations ={'pos_1': ['X'] * 28 + ['T'] * 21 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 28,
            'pos_2': ['X'] * 29 + ['T'] * 22 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 26,
            'pos_3': ['X'] * 29 + ['T'] * 22 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 26,
            'pos_4': ['X'] * 29 + ['T'] * 22 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 26}
```

#### Function with `dict`:

```
def weighted_list(data: dict, list_len: int) -> list:

    return [[random.choice(v) for v in data.values()] for _ in range(list_len)]
```

#### Implementation with `dict`:

```
print(weighted_list(equations, 3))

>>> [['T', 'T', 'X', 'X'],
     ['T', 'X', 'T', 'G'],
     ['T', 'G', 'G', 'T']]
```

- The question specifies, in bold, to return a `list` of weighted random strings.

#### Function with `list`:

```
data_list = [pos_1, pos_2, pos_3, pos_4]  # equations in original form, not a dict

def weighted_list(data: list, list_len: int) -> list:

    return [[random.choice(v) for v in data] for _ in range(list_len)]
```

#### Implementation with `list`:

```
print(weighted_list(data_list, 3))

>>> [['T', 'T', 'X', 'X'],
     ['T', 'X', 'T', 'G'],
     ['T', 'G', 'G', 'T']]
```

#### With a `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(weighted_list(data_list, 6))
```

[image]

#### Combined with your `stats` code:

```
stats = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
stats = stats.apply(lambda x: x.div(x.sum())*100).round(1).fillna(0)
stats.style.background_gradient(cmap='Greys', axis=None)
```

[image]

#### To `numpy`:

```
data_record = stats.to_records()
print(data_record)

rec.array([('B', 33.3, 33.3, 16.7, 33.3), ('G', 33.3,  0. , 50. , 50. ),
           ('T', 33.3, 33.3, 16.7,  0. ), ('X',  0. , 33.3, 16.7, 16.7)],
          dtype=[('index', 'O'), ('0', '<f8'), ('1', '<f8'), ('2', '<f8'), ('3', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [pos_1, pos_2, pos_3, pos_4]
[''.join([random.choice(i) for i in x]) for _ in range(10)]
```

Output sample

```
['TTGX',
 'BXTB',
 'XTBX',
 'GTTG',
 'XXBB',
 'BGXX',
 'XTXT',
 'XTTG',
 'TGBB',
 'TGXX']
```

---

You can do the initialization via

```
x = [['X'] * 28 + ['T'] * 21 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 28, ['X'] * 29 + ['T'] * 22 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 26, ['X'] * 29 + ['T'] * 22 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 26, ['X'] * 29 + ['T'] * 22 + ['B'] * 23 + ['G'] * 26]

[''.join([random.choice(i) for i in x]) for _ in range(10)]
```

---

To automatic the process, try

```
weight = [[28,21,23,28], [29,22,23,26],[29,22,23,26],[29,22,23,26]]
alp = [['X'], ['T'], ['B'], ['G']]
x = [sum([w[i]*alp[i] for i in range(len(alp))], []) for w in weight]
print([''.join([random.choice(i) for i in x]) for _ in range(10)])
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate the initialization with something like stats.to_numpy()? This returns an array of weights but not the associated characters.

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin Output like `['TXXB', 'BTGT', 'XGBX', 'GTTB', 'GBGG', 'XBGX', 'TBGT', 'TGGB', 'XGGX', 'XXGG']` is not you want?

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin Do you mean to simplify the initialization?

Comment: Well imagine that the string has a length of 50. I would like to use something like stats.to_numpy() (see OP) to pull out the weights so I don't manually type them out.

Comment: Yes! Is there a way to make the weight variable a numpy array? I tried this and got: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin `weight = np.array([[28,21,23,28], [29,22,23,26],[29,22,23,26],[29,22,23,26]])`?

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin you can't do `'x'*0.7`, `'x' `can only multiplied by an integer here.

Comment: This solution isn't working if my array of weights is large, like this for example: `array([[27, 29, 28, 29, 29, 28, 28, 30, 28, 26, 26, 27, 28, 29, 27, 28,
        30, 26, 25, 26],
       [21, 22, 21, 20, 19, 20, 20, 20, 19, 21, 23, 23, 19, 19, 21, 20,
        18, 21, 23, 24],
       [22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22, 23, 24, 22, 22, 25, 25, 24, 25,
        25, 25, 25, 23],
       [28, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 26, 28, 28, 27, 26, 26, 25, 26, 26,
        25, 26, 25, 25]])`

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin Yes, that's because you need the corresponding `alp` which has the same number of elements as  `x` has.

Comment: But the number of elements in `alp` doesn't change. Imagine the table in OP with way more columns but same number of rows.

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin I suggest asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

To get weights:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

strings = ['XYVA', 'YXYX', 'XAVY', 'XAVY', 'XAAY', 'AXAV', 'AXYV', 'AXXV', 'AXXV', 'AXXV', 'AXXV']

counts = Counter(chain(*strings))
total = sum(counts.values())

freq = {char: (count / total) for char, count in counts.items()}
```